# Terraform login issue

Tags: ubuntu, terraform, terraform-cloud

When I was trying command

`terraform login`

to enter api key from terraform cloud in my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS local machine, I get the following error:

Token for app.terraform.io:
Enter a value: Gtk-Message: 21:26:02.712: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
Gtk-Message: 21:26:02.868: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 21:26:02.873: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

I tried to install canberra module by this command:

`sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module`
.
But the issue still persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: It isn't clear to me why `libcanberra` would be involved in running `terraform init`. Do you have a "credentials helper" configured on your system to tell Terraform to store credentials in your system keychain?

Comment: This is `login` and not `init`, but the comment is otherwise valid given terraform is distributed as a statically linked binary executable. This is probably an issue with the system environment that is merely evinced during the command execution.

Comment: Sorry I meant `terraform login` not `terraform init`. 